# Eclipse e Selenium - Transformando .JAVA em .EXE ou .BAT

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, batch, .exe

Estou usando o Eclipse e o framework do Selenium pra criação de rotinas automatizadas de abertura de página da Internet e execução de comandos (cliques em links, preenchimento de campos, mudança de site etc). Já consegui criar algumas rotinas teste e todas funcionam muito bem.

Como próximo passo, eu queria transformar um arquivo JAVA que tenho com comandos do Selenium em um arquivo executável (EXE ou BAT, por exemplo). Ou saber como executar esse JAVA via Prompt de Comando, sem depender do Eclipse pra rodá-lo.

Answer (score -1):

Se o seu arquivo é um .jar executável e não um .jar pacote você pode rodar esse comando no prompt:

```
java -jar  meuJar.jar
```